# File descriptors in Android don't seem to get closed

Tags: android, c, linux

I'm working on an app that handles TCP/UDP streams in Android native code, but closing the streams doesn't really seem to work. What I mean is, when I first initiate a TCP connection, I get something like id 43, which I redirect to a pipe. When I close the connection (along with the file descriptor), I start a new connection, but instead of getting the same pipe id, this time I jump to something like pipe 53.

A few more open/close operations and I get to pipe 56, which then for some other reason fails to handle input correctly and my program crashes. I'm testing the closing of the fd's with

```
if (close(fd) < 0) {
  /*log it */
}
```

and it never reports an error, but the file descriptor ids keep incrementing, until I restart the program, then they go back to 40-something.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!